# How to make JAWS screen reader read elements in wpf application sequentially?

Tags: wpf, jaws-screen-reader

I have a WPF application window where user needs to enter their username and password to log in.

As shown in the following image.
[wpf window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9v7Q.png)

I want JAWS to read the text like this.

My Application
Login window
Enter your username and password

and the keyboard focus should be inside username textbox when the window is loaded.

This means JAWS should read the elements sequentially. How to achieve this?
If I create a hidden element and then focus on it to read the required text then keyboard focus can't go on the username textbox.